# is the task shown?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I want to find out is the task actual shown or not. (Possible it's not shown by filter, or the outline structure is collapsed)

I want to handle it in VBA.

Comment: When new to MS Project vba, it's hard to know where to even start. This question has value as it is asking for something many people would find useful. Please don't close it.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if a task is visible, all that is really needed is to use the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method of the [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application) object which returns True if visible. However, the Find method moves the active cell to that task if found and selects the entire row. This is often undesirable for the end-user.

This function returns True/False depending on if the task is visible, and resets the active cell.

```
Function TaskIsVisible(uid As Long) As Boolean

    Dim curTaskUID As Long
    curTaskUID = ActiveCell.Task.UniqueID
    Dim curField As String
    curField = ActiveCell.FieldName
    
    TaskIsVisible = Application.Find("Unique ID", "equals", uid)

    Application.Find "Unique ID", "equals", curTaskUID
    Application.SelectCellLeft
    Do While ActiveCell.FieldName <> curField
        SelectCellRight
    Loop
    
End Function
```

Note: Any task field can be used with the Find method and the field does not have to be in the current view. Unique ID is best in this case since it's guaranteed to not match any other task.

Comment: If you are to implement this code block, I would recommend setting the `ScreenUpdating` property of the MS Project Application to false (`Application.ScreenUpdating = false`) before the first time the `Find` method is called, then set it back to true at the end of the function

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the Find method works but
- it is language sensitive
- it moves the cursor to the task

Are there some other ideas to realize?